# Heuristic Evaluation of an Electric Vehicle

Tags: usability, heuristics, ergonomics, human-factors-engineering

I am looking for a methodology for Heuristic validation/testing of electric vehicle driver touch points. Not specific to digital features (cluster, touch radio display, etc.) but also physical features such as cup holders, seat adjustment and HVAC knobs/controls.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll find anything as specific as you mention. However, you can use [**UX heuristics for physical design**](https://dorve.com/blog/ux-research/ux-heuristics-for-physical-design/) on the one hand *(Disclaimer: I wrote this article)* and other types of heuristics like [**Shneidermann's 8 golden rules**](https://www.cs.umd.edu/users/ben/goldenrules.html) for digital heuristics.

Anyway, I assume you come from an electronics or automotive engineering background, so you probably have some heuristics you're familiar with. However, I'm sure you'll need more guidelines to create a compact set of heuristics that you can use in your project. I hope that the heuristics mentioned in my article will be helpful to you. There are **77 heuristics for physical design** and links to rules and digital design heuristics that may help you.